# OutOfMemoryError Java heap space

Tags: java, tomcat

We had production environment on tomcat 5.5 with JDK6. Last week upgraded the system to tomcat 7 JDK 7. Since then we are getting OutOfMemoryError on daily basis.

I added flags to capture heap dumps on OOM. Analyzed them using Memory Analyzer Tool. Dumps show a suspected object `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog` Shallow size of ~56B and retained size ~1.3 GB with the following stack traces

```
http-apr-8080-exec-36
  at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.getBytes(Ljava/lang/String;)[B (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry; (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry; (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/jar/JarEntry; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/URL; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run()Ljava/net/URL; (Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.privateutil.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.hasNext()Z (ServiceFinder.java:362)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.privateutil.ServiceFinder.toArray()[Ljava/lang/Object; (ServiceFinder.java:228)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.privateutil.PolicyUtils$ServiceProvider.load(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Object; (PolicyUtils.java:451)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.AssertionValidationProcessor.<init>(Ljava/util/Collection;)V (AssertionValidationProcessor.java:80)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ValidationProcessor.<init>()V (ValidationProcessor.java:69)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ValidationProcessor.getInstance()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/ValidationProcessor; (ValidationProcessor.java:79)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.AlternativeSelector.doSelection(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/EffectivePolicyModifier;)V (AlternativeSelector.java:50)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.WsitPolicyUtil.doAlternativeSelection(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap; (WsitPolicyUtil.java:96)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.WsitPolicyResolver.resolve(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver$ClientContext;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap; (WsitPolicyResolver.java:121)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:953)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (DelegatingParserExtension.java:187)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:334)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;ZLcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtension;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (RuntimeWSDLParser.java:171)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;ZLcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtension;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (RuntimeWSDLParser.java:131)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (WSServiceDelegate.java:267)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)V (WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)V (WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/ws/spi/ServiceDelegate; (ProviderImpl.java:106)
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V (Service.java:92)
  at org.tempuri.Trans.<init>()V (Trans.java:42)
  at mposclient.MPOSClient.RetailerTransaction(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (MPOSClient.java:21)
  at WebService.IMTOPUP.topupAmount(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (IMTOPUP.java:170)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InstanceResolver.java:246)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InvokerTube.java:146)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet; (EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/NextAction; (SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube; (Fiber.java:629)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube; (Fiber.java:588)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube; (Fiber.java:573)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet; (Fiber.java:470)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/WebServiceContextDelegate;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/TransportBackChannel;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet; (WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/WSHTTPConnection;)V (HttpAdapter.java:515)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/WSHTTPConnection;)V (HttpAdapter.java:285)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ServletAdapter.java:143)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V (WSServletDelegate.java:155)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V (WSServletDelegate.java:189)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (WSServlet.java:76)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:647)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:728)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardContextValve.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (ErrorReportValve.java:99)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AccessLogValve.java:936)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V (CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AbstractProtocol.java:589)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V (AprEndpoint.java:1852)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Unknown Source)
```

another one with a similar stack trace

```
http-apr-8082-exec-58
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf([BI)[B (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.getBytes(Ljava/lang/String;)[B (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry; (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry; (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/jar/JarEntry; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/URL; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run()Ljava/net/URL; (Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next()Z (Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements()Z (Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.privateutil.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.hasNext()Z (ServiceFinder.java:362)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.privateutil.ServiceFinder.toArray()[Ljava/lang/Object; (ServiceFinder.java:228)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.privateutil.PolicyUtils$ServiceProvider.load(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/Object; (PolicyUtils.java:451)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.AssertionValidationProcessor.<init>(Ljava/util/Collection;)V (AssertionValidationProcessor.java:80)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ValidationProcessor.<init>()V (ValidationProcessor.java:69)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.ValidationProcessor.getInstance()Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/ValidationProcessor; (ValidationProcessor.java:79)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.policy.AlternativeSelector.doSelection(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/EffectivePolicyModifier;)V (AlternativeSelector.java:50)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.DefaultPolicyResolver.doAlternativeSelection(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap; (DefaultPolicyResolver.java:110)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.DefaultPolicyResolver.resolve(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver$ClientContext;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap; (DefaultPolicyResolver.java:66)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:953)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (DelegatingParserExtension.java:187)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:334)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/XMLEntityResolver$Parser;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/XMLEntityResolver;ZLcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtension;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (RuntimeWSDLParser.java:252)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.model.wsdl.WSDLModel$WSDLParser.parse(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/XMLEntityResolver$Parser;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/XMLEntityResolver;ZLcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtension;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/model/wsdl/WSDLModel; (WSDLModel.java:183)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyResourceLoader.getWsdlModel(Ljava/net/URL;Z)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/model/wsdl/WSDLModel; (PolicyResourceLoader.java:81)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser.parseModel(Ljava/net/URL;Z[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMapMutator;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/model/wsdl/WSDLModel; (PolicyConfigParser.java:223)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser.parseModel(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMapMutator;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/model/wsdl/WSDLModel; (PolicyConfigParser.java:185)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyConfigParser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMapMutator;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap; (PolicyConfigParser.java:103)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.WsitPolicyResolver.resolve(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver$ClientContext;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap; (WsitPolicyResolver.java:106)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:953)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (DelegatingParserExtension.java:187)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.postFinished(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtensionContext;)V (WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:334)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;ZLcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/policy/PolicyResolver;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtension;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (RuntimeWSDLParser.java:171)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;ZLcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/Container;[Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/wsdl/parser/WSDLParserExtension;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (RuntimeWSDLParser.java:131)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/model/wsdl/WSDLModelImpl; (WSServiceDelegate.java:267)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)V (WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)V (WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/ws/spi/ServiceDelegate; (ProviderImpl.java:106)
  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V (Service.java:92)
  at com.eservglobal.soaptopupsuite.Soaptopupsuite.<init>()V (Soaptopupsuite.java:42)
  at telenor.vas.voms.PrepaidRecharge.AnyTopup(Ltelenor/vas/voms/VoMSCommon;Lcom/eservglobal/soaptopupsuite/Session;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String; (PrepaidRecharge.java:106)
  at telenor.vas.voms.PrepaidRecharge.PrepaidRecharge(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String; (PrepaidRecharge.java:35)
  at telenor.vas.topup.TopUpWS.TopUp(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ltelenor/vas/topup/PaymentResponse; (TopUpWS.java:468)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InstanceResolver.java:246)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (InvokerTube.java:146)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet; (EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/NextAction; (SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube; (Fiber.java:629)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube; (Fiber.java:588)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube; (Fiber.java:573)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet; (Fiber.java:470)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/WebServiceContextDelegate;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/server/TransportBackChannel;)Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Packet; (WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/WSHTTPConnection;)V (HttpAdapter.java:515)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/WSHTTPConnection;)V (HttpAdapter.java:285)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (ServletAdapter.java:143)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V (WSServletDelegate.java:155)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V (WSServletDelegate.java:189)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (WSServlet.java:76)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:647)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:728)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardContextValve.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (ErrorReportValve.java:99)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AccessLogValve.java:936)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V (CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AbstractProtocol.java:589)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V (AprEndpoint.java:1852)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Unknown Source)
```

I suspect this problem occurs because i'm calling another webservice.

I am using the following JVM options with minimum memory set to 500m and maximum to 1500m

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=170m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\heaplogs\
```

Comment: Why not just upgrade to the a newer Tomcat?

Comment: How much heap have you allowed?  I suspect Java 7 might need a little more (possibly a few 100 MBs) but if it is much more than this I would be surprised. BTW I would make sure you have Java 7 update 25 - 40.

Comment: 1500 MB heap space. Tomcat 7.27 is already there. I must have some reason to upgrade it on production

Comment: I have misread the question (thought you have still Tomcat 5.5). Then I would try to upgrade / downgrade JAX-WS dependencies and see what is happening (https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/memory-leaks-consuming-web-services).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very similar to [this bug](https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/memory-leaks-consuming-web-services).  If its the same, CatalogManager is holding references to every instance of CatalogEntry ever created.  The link suggest you can reuse the same service object but you'll have to reinitialize it each call to force CatalogManger to give up the references its storing.

Another post in the thread suggested trying the below to force the CatalogManger to give up references

```
-Dxml.catalog.staticCatalog=false
```

Personally I've had very good luck with [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) for consuming SOAP if the above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only one obvious thing which i can suppose - you have a memory leak.

You may use `jvisualvm` to detect GC roots which hold references to `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog` objects after ws call. 
It's a very good free tool.

You can find a guides about how to use `jvisualvm` by just googling them.

Answer (score 0):

Open catalina.sh from tomcat/bin.

then

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

=> Restart your tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely ask MAT to show you who is holding those references, why they are still alive and not GCed.

Another option is to try specialised memory leak detection tool, such as [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu).

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you get an OOM its applied that there is some functionality which is causing a memory leak. Finding memory leaks can be difficult but since you have already narrowed down on a suspect. Just check if there is any code in the webservice client which could be causing this.

From the stacktrace my doubt would be with some code in your webservice client which is creating Arrays or copying it.

Also please check if your Vm args are correctly set.